# How to deal with asynchronous nature of Firebase in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In the code that I have written I came to know that my  update() statement is being executed before
the Ondatachange() which is definitely what I don't want since it is returning an null variable .
I want onDatachange()  function to be executed before update() statement. I read some discussions but I wasn't  able to understand how to use it in my code. It would be easy for me to understand with my  code.
here is my code

```
public class Profile extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseUser user;
    private DatabaseReference reference;
    private String userID;
    EditText Username,email;
    String name,mail;
    Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
               Username=findViewById(R.id.Username1);
               email=findViewById(R.id.emailadress);
               button=findViewById(R.id.editinfo);
        user= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        userID=user.getUid();
        reference.child("Driver").child(userID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull  DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                Users usersnapshot=snapshot.getValue(Users.class);
                if(usersnapshot!=null){
                    String username=usersnapshot.getUsername();
                    String Email=usersnapshot.getMail();
                    Username.setText(username);
                    email.setText(Email);


                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull  DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

        }

        public void update(View view){
        if(isNamechanged()||isEmailchanged()){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Data has been updated",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Data has been ted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }


    private boolean isEmailchanged() {
        if (mail == null && !mail.equals(email.getText().toString())) {
            reference.child("Driver").child(userID).child("mail").setValue(email.getText().toString());
            mail=email.getText().toString();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    private boolean isNamechanged() {
        if (name==null && !name.equals(Username.getText().toString())) {
            reference.child("Driver").child(userID).child("username").setValue(Username.getText().toString());
            name=Username.getText().toString();
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }



    }
```

Edit: I forgot to show how is Update() function being  called.I am calling it once I press a button from the layout page itself

```
android:onClick="update"
```

this is the line I used in layout of button

Comment: where do you call update() ?

Comment: I want it to be called after onDatabase() method is executed @DominikWuttke

Comment: what is onDatabase(). When you want to call update() after onDataChanged() is called simply call it at the end of onDataChanged().

Comment: sorry i meant onDataChanged().............Yea but if I just call it throws an error @DominikWuttke

Comment: I think that you might be interested in this article, [How to read data from Firebase Realtime Database using get()?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-firebase-realtime-database-using-get-269ef3e179c5).